# Oscillations in an emission line spectrum

Tags: astrophysics, astronomy, frequency, photon-emission, quasars

From my basic physics background, I know that when an electron gets enough energy from a photon or whatever it may be, it has the capacity to jump up to a specific energy level. When it loses the source of energy that brought it up, it falls back down and releases light.

Now, how would an emission line peak oscillate about a mean frequency value? Does this mean that it goes up and down the energy levels?

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. What do you mean by "emission line peak oscillate about a mean frequency value"?

Comment: It was brought to my attention that after an emission line spectrum of a certain star is generated, physicists can derive an emission line graph from said results. The frequency of the graph can oscillate about a certain value. I just am confused about what would cause these calculations.

Comment: Doppler shift might be responsible - if the star moves towards you the frequency shifts up; when it moves away, frequency shifts down. This is obviously (usually) a fairly slow oscillation. Do you have any idea of the time scale you are expecting for your oscillations?

Comment: Humm... I don't know about a time scale, unfortunately, but I do know that it just oscillates about the mean frequency value by 1%. And this makes sense with what you're saying, as you said that it should be a fairly slow oscillation. I now just have to ponder about how this can be quantitatively answered as well. You gave me much to think about, thank you

Comment: I wonder if the OP is asking about line broadening?  https://apatruno.files.wordpress.com/2015/09/broadening.pdf